# Can I use others people's code from github?

Tags: github

Can I use others people's code from github in my own closed code project without putting any copyrights and links to original author? Legally, not ethically.

Comment: This is going to depend on the license for the project.  In any case, it is off-topic here.  Check programmers.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Depends on the license. Read the license for each project you want to reuse and see if the license permits you to use the code in your closed source project. Some of the most popular licenses on Github (BSD and MIT) will allow you to use the code in your project, but there are terms that you must follow (read the respective licenses to figure out what those terms are). Many licenses require attribution, meaning that you cannot legally reuse their work without some form of attribution (whether it's including a copy of their license, linking to the original author, whatever). Off the top of my head, BSD and MIT both require that you reproduce the full license of the work in any redistribution, binary or source.

Also, regardless of license (and even license terms), attribution is always the right thing to do. Give acknowledgement to the authors of the libraries that you use, even if their license doesn't explicitly require it. Don't be a jerk.

Also, when in doubt, email the author.