# ListBoxFor is case insensitive

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net-mvc, razor, drop-down-menu

In select I have 2 options with same text, but different case: `test` and `TEST` as example.

From server I receive only one selected item test. But on UI I see both `test` and `TEST` are selected.

```
var tagsList = Model.AllTags.Select(t => new SelectListItem
{
    Value = t,
    Text = t
});

<div id="tags-list-container" class="review-tags__select" style="display: none;">
    @Html.ListBoxFor(m => m.SelectedTags, tagsList, new { id = "tags-list-box" })
</div>
```

Is there any solution to make difference between my options ?

---

Firstly I thought it is caused by 3rd-party library for multiple select `SumoSelect` but later I've tried to use native multiple select and same thing happens - in result I have 2 selected options.

---

UPD:

Currently my thoughts about setting selected values using jquery, something like this:

```
$('#tags-list-box').val('test');
```

But it will be better to have this in ListBoxFor extension as for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Internally the `ListBoxFor()` method generates its own `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` to set the `Selected` property based on the value of the property your binding to.

From the [source code](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetWebStack/blob/master/src/System.Web.Mvc/Html/SelectExtensions.cs), you can see that the `private static IEnumerable<SelectListItem> GetSelectListWithDefaultValue()` compares the values using `StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase` so a value of `"test"` and `"TEST"` both match and both options would be set with the `selected="selected"` attribute.

If you want to use a `HtmlHelper` methods to generate the correct html to account for case sensitive values, then you will need to write your extension method (use the source code as a template for your code.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yes, I looks like the best solution for me, but is there an easier way to implement it except copying all `ListBoxFor` methods from source file? (Whem I've tried I need to copy at least 4 methods that used in `ListBoxFor` method)

Comment: Not sure what you mean by _easier way_. The in-built `ListBoxFor()` method ignores case, so if you do not want that behavior, then you need to write your own code. You could of course use JavaScript to modify the html after the page has been rendered, but that would be a nightmare to maintain and test, so if you want a robust solution, then copying and modifying the source code is the easiest way.

Comment: One more question - In case I take code from github with small change, should I add some licence that I use modified code from microsoft?

Comment: Perhaps [this Q/A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7066113/can-i-use-others-peoples-code-from-github) will help

Comment: Thanks, I've read this license, but still don't understand how correctly place all that information (copyrights and licence) in my project... Googling also didn't give me example(structure of project and files) how it should looks like, only text...

Comment: I don't really see a problem - its an open source project. Just add a comment block at the top of your file noting the code is adapted from the source code (add link to it) to provide a case sensitive `ListBoxFor()` method.Not only are you acknowledging the code your adapting, it would be useful for others looking at your code in the future.

Comment: Thanks  @Stephen Muecke :)